# I keep getting a type error when I try to render an EJS page... ,can someone have a look?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Here is the index.js code

```
    enter code here
    CODE
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const path = require('path');

    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))enter code here // for parsing application/x- 
    www-form-urlencoded
    app.use(express.json()) // for parsing application/json
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
    app.set('view engine','ejs')

    const comments = [
        { 
            id:1,
            username: 'tom',
            comment: 'lol'
        },
        {
            id:2,
            username: 'joy',
            comment : 'lmao'
        },
        {
            id:3,
            username: 'ango',
            comment: 'lwkm'
        },
        {
            id:4,
            username: 'shaiyen',
            comment: 'leemao'
        }
    ]

    app.get('/comments',(req,res) => {
        res.render('comments/index',{comments})
    })
 
    app.get('/comments/new', (req,res) =>{
        res.render('comments/new')
    })

    app.post('/comments',(req,res) =>{
        const {username,comment} = req.body;
        comments.push({username,comment})
        res.redirect('/comments');
    })

    app.get('/comments/:id',(req,res) =>{
        const{id}= req.params;
        const comment = comments.find(c => c.id === parseInt(id));
        res.render('comments/show',{comment})
    })

    app.get('/tacos',(req,res) => {
        res.send("GET /tacos response")
    })

    app.post('/tacos', (req,res) =>{
        const  {meat, qty} = req.body;
        res.send(` here are your ${meat} and ${qty} tacos`)
    })

    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("listening on port 3000")
    })
```

While here is the html file

```
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Show</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your comment<%= comment.id %> </h1>
    <h2><%= comment.comment - comment.username %> </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

It keeps showing this error[TypeError: C:\Users\BARINE\Downloads\game\stuff\getpost\views\comments\show.ejs:10
8|

```
9| <body>
```

> > 10|
> >
> > ## <%= comment.id %>

```
11|     <h2><%= comment.comment - comment.username %> </h2>

12| </body>

13| </html>
```

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
at eval ("C:\Users\BARINE\Downloads\game\stuff\getpost\views\comments\show.ejs":12:34)
at show (C:\Users\BARINE\Downloads\game\stuff\getpost\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:703:17)
at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\BARINE\Downloads\game\stuff\getpost\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:36)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\BARINE\Downloads\game\stuff\getpost\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
at View.render (C:\Users\BARINE\Downloads\game\stuff\getpost\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (C:\Users\BARINE\Downloads\game\stuff\getpost\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
at Function.render (C:\Users\BARINE\Downloads\game\stuff\getpost\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\BARINE\Downloads\game\stuff\getpost\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
at C:\Users\BARINE\Downloads\game\stuff\getpost\index.js:50:9
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\BARINE\Downloads\game\stuff\getpost\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skG4O.png)

Comment: which router are you visiting first

Comment: Are you going to /comments/:id? Make sure an individual comment is being passed and not the array of comments.

Comment: find returns undefined if its not found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find you need to do basic checks to see if comment is defined, or redirect/set error etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey So I Just Ran Your Code And Everything Seems to be in order

Now This Error Which You Got

```
Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at eval
```

Is Beacuse the parameter you passing as `id` don't exist in the `comments` array

So when this route is called

```
const comment = comments.find(c => c.id === parseInt(id)); //comment == undefined
```

and thou the error and Ejs compile throw an eval error

Since you new try using try and catch

so your code should be like

```
app.get('/comments/:id',(req,res) =>{
   try{
    const{id}= req.params;
    const comment = comments.find(c => c.id === parseInt(id));
    if(comment){
      res.render('comments/show',{comment})
    }else{
      res.status(404).send("Resource Not Found")
     }
    }catch (err){
      // How you would like to handle your error 
    }
})
```